# Passing values to chart.js - Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am able to fetch data from database which i want to pass to a chart.js.  With the code below,

the chart displays [`"{items: Nike}",total:20"},"{items: Addidas}",total:40"}]` in the xaxis.

But then i want it to display like

```
 categories: ['Nike', 'Addidas'];
```

**Controller**

```
 $items = DB::table('items_tbl')->select('name', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->groupBy('name')
        ->get();
 return view('home',compact('items'));
```

**HTML**

```
<script>
var items_pass = @json($items)
</script>
```

**JS**

```
  xaxis: {
      categories: [JSON.stringify(items_pass)],
      axisBorder: {
        show: true,
        color: '#bec7e0',
      },  
      axisTicks: {
        show: true,
        color: '#bec7e0',
      },    
  },
```